# Calculating Acceptance Rate/Percentage

Tags: mysql, sql, percentage, rate

I have a summary of data talking about status of offers by applicants as follows:

```
Status       Count(status)
accepted        2303
rejected        736
unresolved      75
```

I want to have an acceptance rate by no.of accepted/sum(no.of accepted+no.of rejected)

Could you please help? Thanks so much in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help center pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help) in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Specific pages that you should read include [How Do I Ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please take these introductory steps and then edit your post accordingly.

Comment: I don't accept this. Acceptance rate 0

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can simply do:

```
select (sum(case when status = 'accepted' then cnt else 0 end) /
        sum(case when status in ('accepted', 'rejected') then cnt else 0 end)
       ) as ratio
from t;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon. Appreciate your response. This query throws me an error with cnt as unknown field. Have you used any alias here for count?